# Make alert box overlap content

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5

I try to make the alert boxes overlap on my content but every time it always shows and pushes down my content.
I do not have a z-index anywhere else also change position everything absolute, relative, and fixed but nothing working One time it was working then when I saved it's gone.
here is my code.

```
return (
    <Alert
      dismissible
      show={this.state.show}
      variant={variant}
      onClose={this.handleClose}>
      <div className='container'>
        <Alert.Heading>{heading}</Alert.Heading>
        <p className='alert-body'>{message}</p>
      </div>
    </Alert>
  )
}
}
```

```
.alert {
  align-items: center;
  animation: .5s ease-in-out 0s 1 light-bounce-in;
  bottom: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  // left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 30rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  // right: 0;
  z-index: 1;

  .alert-body {
    margin: auto 0;
  }
}

.close {
  &:active,
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
}

@keyframes light-bounce-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(20%);
  }

  50% {
    transform: translateY(-5%);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your styles are applied on `.alert` but the className of your element is `.container`?

Answer (score -1):

`z-index: 1` seems to be a low value. Try something like `z-index: 100` or `z-index: 1000` or more. I'd check names of classes also.

Comment: Thank you! for your response but it still does not work :'( I'm stuck here like 3 hours